# What's the difference between #define and '=' in C?

Tags: c

for example is there any difference between

```
#define LIMIT 100
```

and

```
int LIMIT= 100;
```

If not is there any use scenario in which on can be used but the other can't?

Comment: Any scenario where an integral constant expression is required

Comment: One defines a preprocessor macro, and the other defines a variable. Preprocessor macros are used to *replace* parts of the code, and are compile-time only constructs. Variables exists as entities in the program, and can change value at run-time. If you need a pointer to a variable, then a macro can't be used. Variables can't be used when compile-time constants are expected.

Comment: In the first case LIMIT is a constant. And it will be "replaced" with the value 100 before compile. You can also write "const int LIMIT = 100;" to declare a constant

Comment: If you feel that one of the answers answered your question, please accept it to make this question more helpful for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one defines a [preprocessor macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Object-like-Macros.html#Object-like-Macros) which will be replaced to its value everywhere in the code during preprocessing.

```
#define SIZE 4

int main() {
    int matrix_1[SIZE][SIZE] = { 0 };
    int* array = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    /* ... */
}
```

The value of `SIZE` cannot be changed at run-time. After preprocessing the code above will be changed to the following:

```
int main() {
    int matrix_1[4][4] = { 0 };
    int* array = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    /* ... */
}
```

The second one initializes an `int` variable which will be allocated on the stack and you can modify it on run-time.

```
int main() {
    int size = 4;
    size = 12; /* size in now 12 */
    int* array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    /* ... */
}
```

The `size` cannot be used in contexts where an integer constant is required, e.g. as a size of a bit field, as a value of an `enum` constant, as `case` label of a `switch` statement, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`#define LIMIT 100` define `LIMIT` as an integer constant while `int LIMIT= 100;` declare it as an integer variable.